# How to import a git repository as a subdirectory of another git repository without losing any commit?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub repositories `TinyDroids` and `Miwok`

`TinyDroids` has a subdirectory `JustJava` and a `README.md`. This has about 10 commits in the log. `Miwok` has about 12 commits in the log.

How can I copy the entire `Miwok` repository as a subdirectory of `TinyDroids` repository?

The resultant `TinyDroids` repository must have two subdirectores: `JustJava` and `Miwok`. Also, it must have its original 10 commits + 12 commits from `Miwok`.

What I tried so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/TinyDroids.git
cd TinyDroids
git clone https://github.com/username/Miwok.git
```

If I commit and push after this, the entire `Miwok` subirectory is shown as a single commit over the 10 commits.

I also tried:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/TinyDroids.git
cd TinyDroids
git pull --rebase https://github.com/username/Miwok.git
```

This gives some issues in rebasing that I do not understand. `git log` after this only show the 12 commits of `Miwok`.

Comment: What is the directory structure of `Miwok`?

Comment: It has many subdirectories and files. `Miwok` is a small android project. So is `JustJava`.

Comment: So do you want to make Miwok a module in the TinyDroids Android Studio project?

Comment: No, I just wanted it to be a separate project. Thanks for the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a branch and merging. You also might need to move the `Miwok` directory to the desired subdirectory. This is a rough sketch of what to do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/TinyDroids.git
$ cd TinyDroids

# Create an orphan branch to pull the Miwok repo to
$ git checkout --orphan miwok
$ git pull https://github.com/username/Miwok.git

# Move the Miwok repo into a subdir
$ mkdir Miwok
$ git mv . Miwok
$ git commit -m "Move Miwok repo to Miwok subdir"

# Merge Miwok into TinyDroids
$ git checkout master
$ git merge miwok
```

The command `git mv . Miwok` won't quite work right. The idea is to move everything to the `Miwok` subdirectory. You might need to do a few more commands to do this more manually.

p.s. Since these are Android Studio projects, you will need to do some housecleaning if you want them to be modules in a single project instead of two separate projects.

Comment: I have to put a `git add .` before git commit, right?

Also, after all these steps, when I do `git log` I only see the old 10 commits + `Move Miwok repo to Miwok subdir` + `Merge branch miwok`. I do not see the 12 commits of `Miwok` repository.

Comment: @SonuMishra what do you see when you do `git branch` and `git log --all`?

Comment: @SonuMishra And no, you do not need `git add .` if you use `git mv`. If you use just plain `mv`, then you will need to also do `git rm` and `git add` as necessary. You can always do `git status` at any time to double-check.